# Copy and Paste special without selecting cell

Tags: excel, vba

The code I have runs but it does not do what I intend in the last line. The line at the end pastes the formula but it does not adjust the formula for the new cell.
As an example If the formula im copying is is A3 and the formula is A3=A1+A2, when it is pasted into A10 the formula is still A1+A2 instead of A9+A8.

I tried using paste special but I cannot get that to work. I do not want to select a new active cell as I will have to return back to the original active cell and reference it again.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Z
'
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim copyRance As Range
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataSheet = Sheets("Macro (insert data)")
    Set destSheet = Sheets("Jun-2019")

    Set StartCell = ActiveCell

    Set copyRange = dataSheet.Range("G4:Q4")
    ActiveCell.Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count).Value = copyRange.Value

    Set copyRange = dataSheet.Range("W4:AG5")
    destSheet.Range("C42").Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count,     copyRange.Columns.Count).Value = copyRange.Value

    Set copyRange = destSheet.Range("N10:X10")
    StartCell.Offset(0, 11).Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count).Value = copyRange.Formula
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered `Range.Filldown` or `Range.Copy Destination:=OtherRange`?

Comment: I have not. I am very new to VBA and coding in general. What do those functions do?

Comment: For example `copyRange.Copy Destination:=ActiveCell` will copy from `copyRange` to `ActiveCell`, including correcting the formulas for relative position. (instead of `ActiveCell.Resize...` et cetera)

Comment: that worked great, is there a way though to then make it paste only the values? This actually wont be necessary for what im doing but good thing to learn.

Comment: @kev12222  `DestCell.Value = SourceCell.Value`

Answer (score 1):

From comments, it seems that you want to copy the Formula, and then convert it to values.  This needs to be done in 2 stages, optionally with an explicit `.Calculate` in case Calculation is set to Manual:

```
Set copyRange = dataSheet.Range("G4:Q4")

'Copy formulas to ActiveCell
copyRange.Copy Destination:=ActiveCell

With ActiveCell.Resize(copyRange.Rows.Count, copyRange.Columns.Count)
    'Force the calculation
    .Calculate
    'Keep just the values
    .Value = .Value
End With
```